# Laravel routing form with method get

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I have a problem with the routing. Currently, I have this on my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'ArticleSiteController@index');
Route::get('article/search/{text}', 'ArticleController@search');
Route::get('article/{url}', 'ArticleController@show');
Route::get('/{url}', 'PageController@index');
```

Routes are being redirected properly except for the search wherein it always use the `ArticleController@show` route.

On the homepage, I have a search form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="http://example.com/article/search/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

It redirects to this url: `http://example.com/article/search/?txtSearch=test` (which is correct) but uses the `ArticleController@show` method instead of the `ArticleController@search`.

Comment: Move the search route above the article/url route. The `{url}` bit matches `search` so it doesn't continue to look for other routes.

Comment: Did that, doesn't work :(

Comment: Mateusz's answer is relevant too. A GET based form creates a query string as you point out article/search/?txtSearch=text. The route you're trying to use needs a third segment article/search/text so the route won't be matched.

Comment: could you update your routes.php in your question after applying Ben Swinburne's answer?

Answer (score 1):

> http://example.com/article/search/?txtSearch=test

It doesn't match `article/search/{text}`

You actually call `http://example.com/article/search/` with `?txtSearch=test` as query string. So it's a proper url for `ArticleController@show` action

```
http://example.com/article/search/test
```

Should be handled by `ArticleController@search`

Query params are additional data passed to specific route, they're not a part of actual route.

Comment: Yeah, I notice that too. How do I set my routes to use `ArticleController@search` whenever it sees a query string?

Comment: Just don't use query string, you've defined routing param {text} for that.

http://example.com/article/search/keyword, not http://example.com/article/search/?searchString=keyword

Comment: Do you think `http://example.com/article/search/test` is better than `http://example.com/article/search/?txtSearch=test` in terms of SEO? Also, im using a form with a get method which automatically adds a '?' and format it as a query parameter on the url. How do make it use `http://example.com/article/search/test` upon clicking the search button then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Route::get('article/search', 'ArticleController@search');`

in your controller use this.

```
public function search(){
    $txtSearch = Input::get('txtSearch');

    $data = MyModel::where('myField','like','%'.$txtSearch.'%')->get();
    return View::make('folder.myFile')->with('data',$data);
}
```

I hope this help you.